# Mongoose unable to get data from MongoDB database

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a model (AccountModel.js) as below and the controller for it. i tried to change one document using postman but i am getting an empty array from the database event though the data is present.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose')
let Schema = mongoose.Schema
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

let mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
account_id:ObjectId,
account_key:String,
message:String,
created_at:Date,
updated_at:Date
})

let MySchema = module.exports = 
mongoose.model('account',mySchema);
module.exports.get = function(callback,limit){
MySchema.find(callback).limit(limit)
}
```

and AccountController as below to manage account db. i have consoled the query and the output from the database.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var Account = require('../models/AccountModel')
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;


exports.setMessage = function(req,res){
query = {account_id:new ObjectId(req.body.acnt_id)}
console.log(query,"...")
Account.find(query,function(err,account_data){
    if(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
    else{
        try{

console.log(account_data,'setWelcomeMessage')
            account_data.message = 
req.body.welcomeMessage
            account_data.updated_at = new Date()
            account_data.save((err,data)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                    res.send(err)
                }
                res.send({"Status":"Success"})
            })
            res.send({"Status":"Success"})  
        }
        catch(e){
            //console.log(e)
            res.send({"Status":"Failed"})
        }
    }
})
}
```

below is the database

```
> db.account.find().pretty()
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c18fea5c5a6a4ebf7999c0b"),
"account_id" : ObjectId("5c18fbefc5a6a4ebf7999c08"),
"account_key" : "UDS1500",
"message" : "testing message",
"created_at" : ISODate("2018-12-18T14:05:25.637Z"),
"updated_at" : ISODate("2018-12-18T14:05:25.637Z")
}
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c18feffc5a6a4ebf7999c0c"),
"account_id" : ObjectId("5c18fbaac5a6a4ebf7999c07"),
"account_key" : "UDS1299",
"message" : "testing message2",
"created_at" : ISODate("2018-12-18T14:06:55.968Z"),
"updated_at" : ISODate("2018-12-18T14:06:55.968Z")
}
```

after calling from POSTMAN i am getting an empty array

Below is the request format

```
{
  "acnt_id":"5c18fbaac5a6a4ebf7999c07",
  "welcomeMessage":"test message 3!!"
}
```

console is as below

```
{ account_id: 5c18fbaac5a6a4ebf7999c07 } '...'
[] 'setWelcomeMessage'
```

what might be the problem in getting empty data? i have wasted a lot of time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you response. I found answer for my problem.

The reason is that the mongoose has created a model with the plural name. Which means, here i have named the model "account". But here in database it will create/connect to a collection with the name "accounts". I dont know the reason for mongoose not creating/connecting to a collection named "accounts". Since there is no collection named with "accounts" it is always giving me the empty result.

At last, i have changed the collection name to "accounts". Now it working fine.

Please comment the reason, mongoose creating/connecting to plural name of the given model.

Answer (score 2):

The culprit is this line

```
query = {account_id:new ObjectId(req.body.acnt_id)}
```

where the statement `new ObjectId(req.body.acnt_id)` creates a new id (regardless of what you pass in the constructor) thus your query fails as there won't be any match in the db. You don't necessarily need to cast the `acnt_id` string to `ObjectId` as Mongoose does this for you under the hood, but if need be use

```
query = {account_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.acnt_id)}
```

otherwise

```
query = {account_id:req.body.acnt_id}
```

will suffice.

---

A better way to do the update would be to use the [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method which does an atomic update of your model and mostly used when you want to update a single document in the db and return it to your application, so you can refactor your controller method to:

```
exports.setMessage = (req, res) => {
    const query = { 'account_id': req.body.acnt_id };
    const update = { 
        '$set': {
            'message': req.body.welcomeMessage,
            'updated_at': new Date(),
        }
    };
    const options = { 'new': true };

    Account.findOneAndUpdate(query, update, options, (err, account_data) => {
        if (err){
            res.send(err)
        }
        else {
            console.log(account_data); // logs the updated account document
            res.send({"Status":"Success"})
        }
    });
}
```

Also, you can set [timestamps](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps) in your schema where mongoose assigns `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields to your schema and the type assigned is `Date` i.e.

```
let mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    account_id: ObjectId,
    account_key: String,
    message: String,
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' } });
```

Answer (score 0):

.find() returns an array, not a single element. Therefore i'd recommend using the .findOne() method instead.

Comment: i am getting null as result even after updating with findOne

Comment: Ok, did you try NOT casting `req.body.acnt_id` to ObjectId? Mongoose should be able to do this on its own. Also, is acnt_id meant to reference another object or do you actually want to "only" store the ObjectId?

Comment: i tried with casting too as shown below. Still it is showing the same . 

    {account_id: new ObjectId(req.body.acnt_id)}

Comment: I actually meant NOT to use new ObjectId() as chridam correctly stated, that this causes problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
//getting from postman .... give the account id in postman
query = {account_id:req.body.acnt_id};
//there is match in DB--- getting the data
Account.find(query,function(err,account_data){
    if(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
u wana update 
    else{
Accoun.update({account_id:req.body.acnt_id},req.body
};
//on body what you enter in postman that will update and store on DB
IN MY KNOWLEDGE 
// just example 
Model.update

Updates all documents matching conditions using the update clause. All update values are casted to their appropriate types before being sent.

var conditions = { name: 'bourne' }
  , update = { $inc: { visits: 1 }}
  , options = { multi: true };

Model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);

function callback (err, numAffected) {
  // numAffected is the number of updated documents
})
```